# Csv to Pandas Dataframe memory error

Tags: python, csv, pandas, memory, dataframe

I am trying to get a 4Gb Csv into a dataframe. I got the memory error. 
I checked the `chunksize` solution but still have the problem.
I have also heard that it could be related to a python version but I am running with anaconda python 3.6 64 bits (at least it is what it is supposed to be)

Here is my function code :

```
import panda as pd    
def dataFrameCreationCsv(path):
        print('Loading Csv file...')
        if file.isfile(path):
            #  dataFrameCsv=pd.read_csv(path,encoding='latin1',delimiter='|')  MEMORY ISSUES ON LARGE SCALE DATASET
            tp = pd.read_csv(path, encoding='latin1', delimiter='|', iterator=True, chunksize=1000)  # gives TextFileReader, which is iterable with chunks of 1000 rows.
            dfCsv = pd.concat(tp, ignore_index=True)
            return dfCsv
        else:
            print('wrong path used')
```

Comment: what is your processor architecture? also how much ram do you have?

Comment: I am running on a windows VM with 12Gb Ram, should switch to 32Gb soon, but this not my biggest Csv...

Comment: Have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17557074/memory-error-when-using-pandas-read-csv

Comment: but how let it be a general function if i have to enter all field types (I have a lot ) to get it run