# MemoryError, pandas read_csv, 32 bit, dont want to use chunksize

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am recently upgrading from python 2 to python 3.(anaconda 32-bit)
Upgrading to 64-bit is not an option at the moment.

Upon calling my function, i am getting a `MemoryError`

```
def M2():
    print ('Loading datasets...')
    e1 = pd.read_csv(working_dir+"E1.txt",sep=',')
```

E1.txt is 300,000 kb.

Is there a better way of reading in this data?

**Update**

1. I do not want to use `chunksize` as this will not read my data in a dataframe.
2. I have narrowed down my .txt file from 300k kb, to 50k kb and still memory issue.

Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-99-99e71d524b4b>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('C:/AppData/FinRecon/py_code/python3/DataJoin.py', wdir='C:/AppData/FinRecon/py_code/python3')

  File "C:\Users\stack\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\anaconda3_32bit\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 827, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "C:\Users\stack\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\anaconda3_32bit\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 110, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

  File "C:/AppData/FinRecon/py_code/python3/DataJoin.py", line 474, in <module>
    M2()

  File "C:/AppData/FinRecon/py_code/python3/DataJoin.py", line 31, in M2
    e1 = pd.read_csv(working_dir+"E1.txt",sep=',')

  File "C:\Users\stack\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\anaconda3_32bit\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 702, in parser_f
    return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)

  File "C:\Users\stack\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\anaconda3_32bit\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 435, in _read
    data = parser.read(nrows)

  File "C:\Users\stack\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\anaconda3_32bit\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 1154, in read
    df = DataFrame(col_dict, columns=columns, index=index)

  File "C:\Users\stack\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\anaconda3_32bit\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 392, in __init__
    mgr = init_dict(data, index, columns, dtype=dtype)

  File "C:\Users\stack\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\anaconda3_32bit\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\construction.py", line 212, in init_dict
    return arrays_to_mgr(arrays, data_names, index, columns, dtype=dtype)

  File "C:\Users\stack\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\anaconda3_32bit\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\construction.py", line 61, in arrays_to_mgr
    return create_block_manager_from_arrays(arrays, arr_names, axes)

  File "C:\Users\stack\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\anaconda3_32bit\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\managers.py", line 1666, in create_block_manager_from_arrays
    blocks = form_blocks(arrays, names, axes)

  File "C:\Users\stack\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\anaconda3_32bit\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\managers.py", line 1734, in form_blocks
    int_blocks = _multi_blockify(items_dict['IntBlock'])

  File "C:\Users\stack\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\anaconda3_32bit\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\managers.py", line 1819, in _multi_blockify
    values, placement = _stack_arrays(list(tup_block), dtype)

  File "C:\Users\stack\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\anaconda3_32bit\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\managers.py", line 1861, in _stack_arrays
    stacked = np.empty(shape, dtype=dtype)

MemoryError
```

Comment: is `E1.txt` properly comma-delimited?

Comment: @MichaelSilverstein Yes it is comma delimited.

Comment: You can use the `chunksize : int, optional` parameter to read your data in smaller chunks if your machine doesn;t have enough memory available for the whole file

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Memory error when using pandas read\_csv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17557074/memory-error-when-using-pandas-read-csv)